# How to resize height of the Dijit TimeTextBox

Tags: dojo

I tried using the following in changing the height of TimeTextBox:

1. `data-dojo-props="style: { height : 16px } "`
   => The arrow button does not change but the box gets smaller.
2. `data-dojo-props="height: '16px' "`
   => Does not work

Comment: thanks... i have reached my daily vote limit but i will vote up in return 2moro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize it you have to do it programatically according to the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/TextBox.html)

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox"]);
<label for="dtb">A default textbox:</label> 
 <input id="ltb" style="height: 10em;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but i believe i wrote the code incorrectly. I meant height and not width. I will update the question.